# css - align divs to occupy full height if browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking at achieving the below image. I am not really sure on how to get the `css` working for the below structure. Should I be making `DIV2` `absolute`?
I want the `nav`, `div1` and `div2` to occupy full height of the broswer.

[image]

My HTML skeletal is as follows.

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div>
                    DIV 1
                </div>
                <div>
                    DIV 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @LukeRamsden, i am talking about `height`

Comment: Could you explain what it is you're trying to do a little bit better? What have you tried?

Comment: @LukeRamsden, updated the Question

Comment: I would use CSS `flex` for this. This is combinable with bootstrap v4 as well. [This litte stuff here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) was an eye opener for me some time ago ;) If you understand `flex` its great for many purposes like yours

Comment: @Stretau, can you please post this as answer based on my structure. I have a `nav` element which is confusing to me.

Comment: @good.learner Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `<html>` and `<body>` to have 100% `height`, then set `height` on the `div`s to however large you want them to be (say 80%), as well as the container for the `div`s. Percentage height is based on the parent of the element.

Answer (score 2):

I have provided a non-bootstrap answer, to help you understand the flexbox.

Setting the parent container to full height is the first step.

```
.container{
     display: flex;
     height: 100vw;
     flex-direction: column; 
}
```

Then by using `flex: 1;` we allow the children to take all the available space.

Last step is to limit the max-height of the second child by using `max-height`.

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXzQNp)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPmqGB) you can find the CSS styles based on your HTML structure. The code is not responsive but it will give you an idea on how to go about solving your own problem.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.container-fluid .row .col-md-6 {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  // 50px is height of the navbar so subtracting it from total height 
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); 
}

.col-md-6 > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.col-md-6 div:first-child {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 400px;
  /*Setting minimum height so height of div will not go below 400px otherwise it will get smaller than div2 due to flex:1
  flex: 1 takes 100% of height - 50px - 100px 
  */
  background-color: red;
}

.col-md-6 div:last-child {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        DIV 1
      </div>
      <div>
        DIV 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use bootstrap grid.
Use flexbox.
Parent div must have 100% height, display: flex and column direction. Think that way.

Comment: Can i achieve the same using bootstrap?

Comment: @good.learner , no, you cann't do that using only bootstrap. Anyway you need to use some custom css.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use *container* class instead of *container-fluid* to have div centered on page
her the code

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>
                DIV 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>
                DIV 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for height you can use **vh css unities** OR use **Felxbox** and if you chose this second solution probably you can use *V4 of BS*